# How can I get armv7a-unknown-linux-android21 toolchain?

Tags: android, c++, gcc, clang

I'm trying to compile some kernel module for the android device. I tried to look which toolchain it uses by installing some C/C++ compiler from GPlay and looking on clang -v output.
It is "armv7a-unknown-linux-android21".
But android NDK r23c has no such toolchain in "toolchains/lvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin" folder and NDK r18b doesn't want to make an standalone toolchain with such a name by using "build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh" script.
How then can I obtain this toolchain?

Comment: I don't see how the android version level is relevant, that only applies to userspace code as it determines which Android-specific headers are available

Comment: The ndk is for building user applications not kernel modules. You'll need the [aosp toolchain](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm_android/+/master/README.md) for the device

Comment: @Botje I'm not sure about what you say. Sorry, I don't know about all this thing a lot. In NDK r23c I have only "arm7v-linux-androidabi**-clang" files and NDK r18b doesn't want to make any toolchain which starts with "armv7a".

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks. Does it mean that "armv7a-unknown-linux-android21" isn't apropriate toolchain for compiling kernel module? If yes: how can I find which do I need? Doesn't any prebuilt binary exist?

Comment: Did you read the link i posted? There are download links there